how to make argparse not mention -h and --help when started with either of them
When running with --help, the help output includes the description of the --help argument itself. How can that line be avoided in the output of --help?
I could not get this answer to work, as the following code demonstrates when run using python 3.10:
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        add_help=False,
        description=f'does foo')
    parser.add_argument('--bar', type=str, required=True, help='the bar value')
    args = parser.parse_args()

The result of running the above script file with --help is an error message, not the help message sans the --help option in it:
usage: scratch_54.py --bar BAR
scratch_54.py: error: the following arguments are required: --bar

I would like to avoid the help option self-referencing itself in its own output, while having the rest of the help message behave as usual.

What you're missing is that add_help=False suppresses adding a help option completely, it's not hiding the option from the help text.

What I'm missing is how to accomplish that, as well.

Try this:
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument("-h,", "--help", action="help", help=argparse.SUPPRESS)

The help action will still be there, and work as usual, but it will be hidden from the help text itself.

Thanks. Would there also be any safe way for taking an already instantiated ArgumentParser object, and apply this change to it?

@matanox No, don't think so.
